# Connection timeout when use ELB with Tomcat

Tags: amazon-web-services, tomcat, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I configured an ELB for **HTTPS with imported SSL** and registered an instance running Tomcat expose **HTTPS port 8443** with the **same SSL**.

When I use postman to test some APIs with the endpoint is ELP, it sometimes returns `Connection timeout` after a long time. However, if I use the endpoint is IP of instance, APIs always work and return immediately.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using https on the load balancer dns or ```https://your-website.com:8443/path``` ?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem. LB didn't work stably because I created LB with an AZ and register instances in another AZ. Therefore, I create a new LB with correct AZs and it worked.